# Python 3 - "file.read(x)" reads x chars, not bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, utf-8

According to documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io#io.RawIOBase.read), `file.read(x)` should return me up to x bytes from file.

When I call `file.read(1)` on a UTF-8 text file, however, it returns me unicode symbols (including those which occupy 2-4 bytes).

In Python 2.7, however, everything seems to be ok.
So the question is - is that a bug, or do i miss something here?

Comment: Did you open the file in binary mode or in text mode?

Comment: @Aran-Fey in text mode. In binary mode it works as it should. But read() operates same on both, i suppose

Comment: Nope. In text mode you get 1 character, in binary mode you get 1 byte.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, hm, ok, then i did't search docs well. Thank you

Comment: When you open in text mode you get a text reader: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io#io.TextIOBase

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != b"":
        byte = f.read(1)
```